# jQuery easeIn/Out for infinite loop?

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop

How can I add easeIn/Out into an infinite animated loop?

Currently the easeIn run-up-to-full-speed is very slow; instead of being a quick 500ms easeIn.

EaseIn/Out - http://jsfiddle.net/53quf/1/

Linear - http://jsfiddle.net/NJXwH/

Comment: I don't get it? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an infinite loop with easing (or even a very long animation of indeterminate length), you'll need to separate the animation into three parts:

1. Easing in at the beginning
2. Animating for a while / forever
3. Easing out at the end

The reason your easeIn is so slow is that its length is based on the full animation time of 60 seconds. jQuery doesn't have easing in or out individually built-in, so you need some sort of [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) for this to work. Here's a jsfiddle that shows the easing in, easing out is left as an exercise for the reader.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ntJm/

Comment: Ah that is a different way of thinking about it. How refreshing.

Any idea how do I allow the animation to pick up from where the mouseout left off?